# Disable resizing a specific column in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using the DataTables jQuery plug-in; http://datatables.net/ Added the third party plugin ColReorderWithResize (http://datatables.net/extras/thirdparty/ColReorderWithResize/) to support table resizing with Datatables.

I am using a table which has fixed pixel width in last column. Is there any way to stop the resizing ability of that column. I want to use it as fixed column width. Here is my initialization function.

```
var oTable = $('#care_and_feed_table').dataTable({
        "sDom": 'Rlfrtip',
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "aaSorting": [],
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            {
                bSortable: false,
                aTargets: [ -1 ]
            }
        ]
    });
```

Better solution would be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/1117/column-width/p1

it help you can use also set width in pixel

see [demo](http://live.datatables.net/#preview)

and also use by this also your problem solve

```
 var oTable = $('#care_and_feed_table').dataTable({
        "sDom": 'Rlfrtip',
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bInfo": false,
"bAutoWidth": false,
        "aaSorting": [],
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            {
                bSortable: false,
                aTargets: [ -1 ]
            }
        ]
    });
```